# Spring Web MVC Thymeleaf themes

Tags: spring, jsp, themes, thymeleaf

I'm currently developing an Spring Web MVC application. For the frontend I have integrated thymeleaf. I don't want to do the whole design myself... So I wondered if there are any default themes that I can use like in wordpress? Or are there any themes for plain jsp sites? Or do I always have to implement the whole design by myself?

Kind regards
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using thymeleaf then no need to use jsp, stick with html and you could take a look at Twitter Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/).